# jQuery failure in javascript_include_tag during migration to Rails 3.1

Tags: jquery, migration, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to migrate an application from Rails 3 to 3.1 and having problems with jQuery. The error is bellow. If I remove 'javascript_include_tag "application"' all works fine (with no javascript), so something javascript-related is missing.

```
Showing C:/.../app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #7 raised:

couldn't find file 'jquery'
  (in C:/.../app/assets/javascripts/application.js:7)
 Extracted source (around line #7):

4:   <title><%= @title unless @title.blank? %></title>
5:   <!-- %= render 'layouts/stylesheets' % --> 
6:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application", :debug => true %>
8:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
9: </head>
10: <body>
```

In my Gemfile I have the entry for jquery-rails:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
....
```

In application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file .......
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//
```

As far as I know that it is the only requirement for working with jQuery in Rails 3.1.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//= require jquery
```

Is a new directive in Rails 3.1, which mentions the jquery.js file required.

In Rails 3.1, the jquery.js and jquery_ujs.js files are located inside the vendor/assets/javascripts directory contained within the jquery-rails gem.

Also, did you do a bundle install ?

More about the asset pipeline at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html.
More about using Javascript in Rails at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives.

Comment: Hi! I just reinstalled jquery-rails again. Then I ran bundle install. I noticed couple things. While uninstalling I saw that there are two jquery-rails gems (jquery-rails-0.2.7 and jquery-rails-1.0.14). I removed both. Then after running 'gem install jquery-rails' only the jquery-rails-1.0.14 was installed. However, after running 'bundle install' I saw the installation for the second one ("Installing jquery-rails (0.2.7)"). So, i guess it is what Rails 3.1 does. One more thing: my vendor\assets\stylesheets has only single .gitkeep file. I am sill getting the same error.

Comment: Files jquery.js and jquery_ujs.js were missing in vendor/assets/javascripts. Added them manually. That is strange though because I reinstalled gems several times. I thought that these files are coming with them.

Comment: These files actually do come with the jquery-rails plugin. Not sure through why they went missing in your case.

Comment: Well... I just created an empty application and there is nothing but .gitkeep inside vendor/assets/stylesheets.

Comment: ohk ... In Rails 3.1, the jquery.js and jquery_ujs.js files are located inside the vendor/assets/javascripts directory contained within the jquery-rails gem. So they are actually in the gem itself. And if the gem is installed for the application they would be available.

Comment: I am confused. But I installed the gems... I have ran bundle install and these gems are in my Gemfile. How else should I install them for the application? Thanks!